# How do I remove all traces of a contributor in a repository in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a global config with `user1` and `email1` that I use for other things. The problem is, I accidentally pushed a commit to GitHub with this global config, which happens to be completely incorrect. I wanted instead to locally config my GitHub user `user2` and `email2` and then push with that one so that on GitHub I appear as the only contributor.

[image]

I tried `git rebase -i` and then `--amend --author="..."` and even a `git filter-branch` script that I found on another question. When I `git log`, indeed the Author is correct, but on GitHub it is still showing that the commit has two contributors now.

[image]

The thing is that the second user shouldn't exist. It is actually me, just with a user name and email that is not on GitHub, but for some reason, GitHub created this user automatically. Is it possible to completely remove this contributor from this repo, either through git or GitHub settings?

Comment: Have you tried pushing your repository to GitHub after you removed the wrong author locally?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes. I also tried refreshing the page, but still the same thing as those printscreens

Comment: Did the push actually work or did you ignore any error messages you got and assumed it worked?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `origin/main` is the same as `main`

Comment: I cloned it to another folder. The commit is there with the correct user, but not on GitHub...

Comment: Check that your *committer* for that commit is correct as well (`git show --pretty=fuller <hash-id>` for instance, or `git log --pretty=fuller`). If so, this isn't a Git thing any more (now that you've made the author correction), it's just a GitHub thing. If not, fix both (adjust your `user.name` and `user.email` setting and use `git commit --amend --reset-author`) and force-push and check again. If and when you get it down to "just" a GitHub thing, you'll need something specific to GitHub at that point.

Comment: @torek you are right. It is `Author: user2 <email2>` and `Commit: user1 <email1>`